# How to count each occurence in a nested list and print progress into console in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, counter

I'm writing a program that is supposed to read a .txt file containing coordinates expressed as N, S, W, E. For example, my test file is:
"NNEEENNW
NSWENNNS"

This function reads the data file and converts the data into a list of list splitting each character.

```
def read_file(file_name):
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        lines = [list(str(line.rstrip().upper())) for line in f]
        return lines
```

So for my file above it gives me

```
[['N', 'N', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'W'], ['N', 'S', 'W', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N','S']]
```

In a Cartesian map at (y, x) starting at (0, 0) each movement to N and E adds 1, and each movement to W and S subtracts 1.

I have this function that gives me the final coordinates:

```
def convert_coodinates(coordinates):
    s = Counter({'N': 0, "S":0, "W": 0, 'E':0})
    for i in coordinates:
        s.update(i)
    final_latitude = s['N'] - s["S"]
    final_longitude = s['E'] - s["W"]
    final = (final_longitude, final_latitude)

    print(final)
```

Sor the example above it would give me:

```
(2, 6)
```

Ideally I would print

```
(2, 4)
(2, 6)
```

Basically it supposed to print the first set of coordinates, then first set + second set...and so on until the last line which would be the final destination.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are updating the `Counter` in the loop all at once and then calculating the latitude and the longitude.

This is causing `s` to only contain the value after accumulating all the list elements together.

Dumping `s` will confirm the same that it has the values `Counter({'N': 8, 'E': 4, 'S': 2, 'W': 2})`.

What you basically need is to calculate the values in each iteration:

```
from collections import Counter
def convert_coodinates(coordinates):
    s = Counter({'N': 0, "S":0, "W": 0, 'E':0})
    for idx, i in enumerate(coordinates):
        s.update(i)
        final_latitude = s['N'] - s["S"]
        final_longitude = s['E'] - s["W"]
        final = (final_longitude, final_latitude)
        
        print(final)

coord = [['N', 'N', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'W'], ['N', 'S', 'W', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N','S']]
convert_coodinates(coord)
```

Output:

```
(2, 4)
(2, 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Emmm, the simple method is that you put the calculation and `print` code into your **for loop**:

```py
def convert_coodinates(coordinates):
    s = Counter({'N': 0, "S":0, "W": 0, 'E':0})
    longitude,latitude = 0,0
    for i in coordinates:
        s.update(i)
        longitude = s['E'] - s["W"]
        latitude = s['N'] - s["S"]
        final = (longitude, latitude)
        print(final)
```

Comment: instead of `+=` use `=`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes!